# Wireless network was connected but no Internet by Realtek 11n usb wireless adapter

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, internet

I am trying to use Windows 8.1 desktop computer to receive wireless Internet from a 4G modem through the help of a Realtek 11n usb wireless adapter that can receive b/g/n/a/c types of signal.

To achieve this task, I have installed its driver using a given small CD when I bought it. I managed to install and make the antenna to detect and receive the wireless Internet signal. However, the Internet connection is not available when browsing the Internet search engines such as Firefox despite the network connection can be established and be observed as "connected". The weird case is that the device manager indicates that the Realtek driver is up-to-date.

How can I do now to get the Internet allowed in my desktop computer, so that I can browse the Internet? Please advice me.

Thank you for your time and advice.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

[Open a command prompt window](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/windows/win8/cmd_prompt.php), then type `ipconfig`. Look for a "gateway" address in a "Wireless LAN" section and then [ping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_%28networking_utility%29) that IP address. I.e., if you see an [IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) address of 192.168.0.2 with a gateway address of 192.168.0.1, you would type the command `ping 192.168.0.1`. Do you see responses showing a time in milliseconds for the gateway, i.e., router, to respond or do you see timeouts? If you see a response, try pinging the Google DNS server at 8.8.8.8, i.e., `ping 8.8.8.8`. Do you see responses or timeouts? If you see timeouts, try using the a [traceroute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute) command - the utility is named `tracert` on Microsoft Windows systems - to see how far you can get beyond your router. I.e., `tracert -d 8.8.8.8`. If you can get all the way to the destination system, then, perhaps the DNS settings on the system you are using are incorrect. You could try an [nslookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nslookup) command specifying that the Google DNS server at 8.8.8.8 should be used for DNS queries. I.e., `nslookup superuser.com 8.8.8.8`. Do you see IP addresses returned for superuser.com?